# No Method Error in show.html.erb, known good works fine, file copy/paste doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running a rails 4./ruby 2.3 environment trying to get a rails app up and working and it's breaking somewhere down the line with the following error:

NoMethodError in Invoices#show 
undefined method `company' for nil:NilClass

```
    <p>
      <strong>Company:</strong>
      <%= @invoice.company %>
    </p>

    <p>
```

Now, I've added alot of styling and edits to this app to build functionality and appearance. That may have broken it and am not sure where. What I did to fix it is make another app with the same "RAILS GENERATE" commands and variables as before, so it's just a basic app. Which DOES work.

Looking at the two app's side by side, within InvoicesController, this is the same:

```
# GET /invoices/1
# GET /invoices/1.json
def show
end
```

When I copy the show.html.erb file from the known good and tested app, I get the following:

NoMethodError in Invoices#show 
undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass

```
<p>
<strong>Amount:</strong>
<%= @invoice.amount %> <%= @invoice.currency %>

</p>
```

I looked at the error from terminal and got this:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".*     
FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by InvoicesController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"14"}
Rendered invoices/show.html.erb within layouts/application 35ms)         Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 68ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

app/views/invoices/show.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_invoices_show_html_erb__4598034618316500664_30241380'
```

Here is the top of the InvoicesController:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController 
before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Can you help? Any ideas?

Comment: what do you have in def set_invoice method ? It seems @invoice variable is not set when you try to view show action hence the error

Comment: Could you show us method ` set_invoice`?

Comment: where is set_invoice method . Can you please paste code of set_invoice method?

Comment: Here is my set invoice

      InvoicesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints betweenactions.
      def set_invoice
      @search = Invoice.search(params[:q])

Comment: Here is the method. Does it need to be made public maybe? 
   
     private
     def set_invoice
     search = Invoice.search(params[:q])
     invoices = @search.result
     end

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've not populated `@invoice` (`nil:NilClass`), hence you cannot call `.company` on it.

You should have the following:

```
#app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def show
   end

   private

   def set_invoice
      @invoice = Invoice.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/invoices/show.html.erb
<%= @invoice.company %>
```

---

> NoMethodError in Invoices#show 
>   undefined method `company' for nil:NilClass

The best way to work *around* (not fix) this is to use the [`.try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method:

```
<%= @invoice.try :company %>
```

Just an FYI in case you hit a similar problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed and corrected the invoices_controller.rb. Pulled out about 29 lines of code and then updated the private method.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @invoice.save
    format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_invoice
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
end
```